# HTML regex ignore tags

Tags: html, regex

In my HTML text I want to ignore two (2) `</tr>`'s and capture text from the start to the third `</tr>`,  my pattern is

```
 string regularExpressionPattern = @"\<tr class=(.*?)\</tr>";
```

And here is the input text.

```
<tr class="oddrow">
  <td>5Dimes.eu</td>
  <td style="text-align:center;">
    <table cellspacing="1" cellpadding="3" class="tablehead">
    <tr>
      <td width="50%" style="text-align:right;">SF: -3<br/>STL: +3</td>
      <td style="text-align:left;">-111<br/>+101</td>
    </tr>
    </table>
  </td>
  <td style="text-align:center;">
    <table cellspacing="1" cellpadding="3" class="tablehead">
    <tr>
      <td width="50%">41.5 O/U</td>
      <td width="50%">o: -106<br/>u: -104</td>
    </tr>
    </table>
  </td>
  <td style="text-align:center;">SF: -160<br/>STL: 150</td>
  </tr>
```

As you can see, there are three (3) `</tr>` tags.
How can I adjust my pattern to use the third tag rather than the first one?

Thanks

Comment: You'd better You'd better use an HTML parser.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: Is this C/Java? Or are you string to implement the above regex in JavaScript? As described in the [regex tag info](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info) - please include a tag for the programming language/tool you are using

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using this regular expression :

```
<tr class=.*?(<tr>.*?</tr>.*?)*</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use

> `@"\<tr class=((.*?)\</tr>){3}"`